# How to Event Target element and change its innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to edit innerHTML of a specific dynamically added DIV using e.target but it returns Null

```js
//im adding e.listener to a whole DIV and targetting specific elements inside that div
todoList.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    let inputText = e.target.closest("span")
    console.log(inputText.innerHTML)
})
```

```html
<ul class="flex todo-list flex-col todo-list h-72 flex-1 overflow-auto">
                    <li class="todo flex justify-between bg-white/30 p-2 px-2 rounded-r-full my-1">
                        <div class="">
                            <span class="input-text">Hello World</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex gap-x-1">
                            <button class="done-todo-btn bg-[#E94560] font-bold px-2 rounded-xl">Done</button>
                            <button class="edit-todo-btn bg-[#16003B] font-bold px-2 rounded-xl">Edit</button>
                            <button class="del-todo-btn bg-[#0F3460] font-bold px-2 rounded-xl">Delete</button>
                        </div>

                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: `div` as direct child of `ul`?

Comment: no its `LI` before it i just didnt copy/paste properly....

Comment: How did you initialized the "todoList".?

Comment: What exactly is `null`? It seems like you’re doing event delegation, but [`closest`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) might fail to find the element. Does it work if you just wrap the `console.log` statement inside an `if(inputText){`…`}`?

Comment: You can use e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("span"); to select the li > span the closest is not working here.

Comment: @Mehrwarz Oh, now I see. That would be `e.target.closest(".todo").querySelector(".input-text")`. You have to find the correct ascendant with `closest` first, then find the correct descendant with `querySelector`.

Answer (score -1):

```html
//im adding e.listener to a whole DIV and targetting specific elements inside that div
todoList.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    //added querySelector
    let inputText = e.target.closest(".todo").querySelector(".input-text")
    console.log(inputText.innerHTML)
})
```

```js
<ul class="flex todo-list flex-col todo-list h-72 flex-1 overflow-auto">
                    <li class="todo flex justify-between bg-white/30 p-2 px-2 rounded-r-full my-1">
                        <div class="">
                            <span class="input-text">Hello World</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex gap-x-1">
                            <button class="done-todo-btn bg-[#E94560] font-bold px-2 rounded-xl">Done</button>
                            <button class="edit-todo-btn bg-[#16003B] font-bold px-2 rounded-xl">Edit</button>
                            <button class="del-todo-btn bg-[#0F3460] font-bold px-2 rounded-xl">Delete</button>
                        </div>

                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).